# What is the purpose of putting Wordpress in a Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, docker

I viewed some video tutorials about Docker container.
Yet it's purpose is still not clear to me.
Would it make sense to use Docker for relatively little Wordpress projects as a normal Webdesigner?
When does it make sense to use it in conjunction with Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of reasons I can think of

### As a demo

Lots of people are familiar with Wordpress so it works well as an example of using Docker. You create the MySQL container and then the Wordpress container, which links to MySQL, and then you've got a simple application built from two pieces.

### As a packaging system

You can think of Docker as an alternative way to install software. Rather than getting the right versions of PHP and MySQL installed and configuring plugins, you can just fetch a Wordpress image that's configured correctly.

In the context of a Rails app, the first part of getting the app working is to fetch a bunch of dependencies. This leads to the possibility that your app worked in development but some server is inaccessible and your app can't be deployed. Or you depended on some system tool without thinking about it, and the tool is only on your dev machine. Packaging your app in Docker means that you either have the image on the server (so everything's installed and working) or you don't (and it's obvious why your app isn't running).

### For isolation and security

You can run multiple Wordpress instances in separate containers just like many providers do with VMs.

If someone's Wordpress server gets broken into, you've still got Docker isolating them from the other Wordpress instances and the hosting server. You can assign resource limits on containers so that nobody can hog the CPU or memory.

It's also trivial to run multiple versions of Wordpress side by side, even if they have incompatible dependencies.

### As a development environment

(This doesn't really apply to Wordpress, unless you're involved in Wordpress development.)

One of my favorite uses of Docker is to take our production images, run them locally (giving me a personal copy of our production system) and then run destructive tests against my environment. When the tests are done, I restart all the containers and I'm right back to my starting state. And I can hunt for regressions by standing up a second complete system using last week's images and comparing the two systems' responses to the same requests.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is useful for creating simple, binary-like building blocks for deploying complex applications. Personally, I use it for simple ones as well, as it reduces the number of things that you have to worry about and increases the repeatability of deployment tasks, but there are plenty of other tools (VMs, Chef, etc) that will help with that too, so YMMV.